# Error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, timer

reason: '-[Arr setTime:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400027ca80'"

Arr is data model entity that contains only one attribute ('time' of type string) and 'array' is not empty.

i think it has to do something with '@objc func updateTime()' and 'Timer' in viewDidLoad

```
    var array = [Arr]()
    var ringTime = Arr()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            if array.contains(ringTime){
                print("HELLO")
            }

        }

    @objc func updateTime() {
            ringTime.time = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: NSDate() as Date, dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
        }

func getData() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {
             array = try context.fetch(Arr.fetchRequest())
             items = try context.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
        }catch{
            print("failed to get the data")
        }

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYE4s.png)

in other viewcontroller (adds data to Arr) :-

```
@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let entity  = Item(context: context)
    let entity2 = Arr(context: context)
    entity.time = timeLbl.text
    entity.isOn = true
    entity2.time = timeLbl.text
    saveData()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

these are further details :-

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:

    0x10d0b9d38 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x10d0b9d3d <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x10d0b9d40 <+8>:  syscall 
    0x10d0b9d42 <+10>: jae    0x10d0b9d4c               ; <+20>
    0x10d0b9d44 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10d0b9d47 <+15>: jmp    0x10d0b2caf               ; cerror_nocancel
->  0x10d0b9d4c <+20>: retq   
    0x10d0b9d4d <+21>: nop    
    0x10d0b9d4e <+22>: nop    
    0x10d0b9d4f <+23>: nop
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of Arr, Thanks

Comment: when / where does it crash please specify?

Comment: it is giving me error while running @objc func updateTime().

Comment: Arr is the entity (type of class) name

Comment: If you know the purpose of ViewDidLoad, you should ask yourself "Why am I even using the Timer in ViewDidLoad in the first place?"

Comment: would it solve the problem if i use it in some other function?

Answer (score 0):

Since the exact point of exception is unknown, the issue must be when comparing `ringTime` in `array`,

```
    if array.contains(where: { (arr) -> Bool in
        arr.time == ringTime.time
    }) {
        print("Hello")
    }
```

I might me able to help you more with some more information.

Comment: it is giving me error while running @objc func updateTime() block

Comment: Show the implementation of `Arr`.

Comment: i have added an image that shows details about the entity and also an a button functions which adds data to the entity or entities and also a function to fetch data from the entities

Answer (score 0):

I dont see implementation of `Arr`.

Guessing that this is probably missing `@objc` in front of `time` variable.

Comment: i have added an image that shows details about the entity and also an a button functions which adds data to the entity or entities and also a function to fetch data from the entities